# Proxmox KVM IPv6 Routed not working

Tags: ipv6, proxmox, isc-dhcp, debian-stretch, ndp

I got a /48 v6 assigned by my Provider with a dedicated server, on which I did install Proxmox 5.

My Issue is, that the dhcpdv6 should assign the VM a fixed ip, but it does not get the IP assigned. I also deployed a ndpd.

My current network config is the following:

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address  2a03:xxxx:xxxx::1
    netmask  48
    post-up /sbin/ip -6 route add 2a03:xxxx:xxxx::1 dev eth0
    post-up /sbin/ip -6 route add default via 2a03:xxxx:xxxx::1
    pre-down /sbin/ip -6 route del default via 2a03:xxxx:xxxx::1
    pre-down /sbin/ip -6 route del 2a03:xxxx:xxxx::1 dev eth0

iface vmbr1 inet6 static
    address  2a03:xxxx:xxxx::2
    netmask  48
    up ip -6 route add 2a03:xxxx:xxxx::/48 dev vmbr1
```

My current ndpd config:

```
route-ttl 30000

proxy vmbr1 {
   router yes
   timeout 500   
   ttl 30000
   rule 2a03:xxxx:xxxx::/48 {
    auto
   }
}
```

dhcpd6 config:

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

authoritative;
deny unknown-clients;

subnet6 2a03:xxxx:xxxx::/48  {
        option dhcp6.name-servers 2606:4700:4700::1111,2606:4700:4700::1001;
}

host vm1 {
  hardware ethernet 00:0D:87:B3:AE:A6;
  fixed-address6 2a03:xxxx:xxxx:0001:0000:0000:0000:0001;
}
```

With single IPv6 addresses it works just fine with neigh add proxy, I suspect its even a DHCP issue. Does anyone got an idea?

Comment: When I configure IPv6 on the KVM static, I can ping only vmbr1 but not the actual gateway dang it. Seems like its a routing + dhcp problem.

Comment: Replacing npdpd with radvd makes it possible to reach vmbr1 without static configuration. Still the VM has not directly a IP assigned by DHCP and is still unable to reach the Gateway.

Comment: You can't have the same subnet on two different interfaces (without a whole lot of unnecessary grief, which your IPv6 /48 makes unnecessary anyway). You need to first set up your IPv6 address/64 for the server, then route (the rest of) the /48 to your virtual networks. Remember that IPv6 subnets should always be /64.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well then, I have splitted the /48 in multiple /64 subnets. Somwhow the VM is unable to ping the Node gateway now and the route vent missing, strange.